# Sublime Text is autocorrecting “^”

Tags: macos, keybindings, sublimetext

I use Sublime Text 3 for my LaTeX coding. Whenever I try to type something with a carat such as `e^{x+2}` it autocorrects it to `e{{x+2}}`. The autocorrect occurs right after typing the first curly brace and only occurs in math mode.

I've looked through my Key Binding settings but it all looks pretty foreign to me. This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140169/sublime-text-snippets-just-for-latex) here seems to refer to adding this autocorrection, but again is tough for me to understand what is going on.

Comment: What plugins do you have installed, if any?

Comment: Sublime adds settings via JSON, which can look rather obtuse to those unfamiliar with the format. There is some [documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/key_bindings.html) regarding this, with a handy table. But, per @MattDMo, it would be good to confirm if you have any plugins installed before doing any changes there.

Comment: I can't replicate this on Windows using the default install of version 3.2.2. I created a new document with LaTeX syntax and just typed `e^{x+2}`, no other headers or directives. I'll try it on my Mac later.

Comment: Just tried this on my Mac as well to confirm, checking that the document syntax was correct, and could enter this without issue. I'm using Sublime 3.2.2, Build 3211 on macOS 11.2.1.

Comment: @MattDMo: If you mean packages, I have Colorsublime, LaTeXing, Package Control, Side Bar, SideBarTools, StatusBarTime, SublimeOnSaveBuild, LaTeXTools, LaTeXYZ

Comment: @karolus: I have a Mac and Sublime Version 3.2.2, Build 3211 as well but this has been happening for a while over various versions/builds.

Comment: I searched through the keybinding file and found a binding starting with `{ "keys": ["{"], "command": "wrap_block", "args": {"begin": "{", "end": "}"}, "context":` (on line 405 for me). This seems to be source of the autocorrecting, but no edit I've made seems to work. I also realized it only happens in math mode (I'll edit my original post to reflect that also)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you try turning off spell check. Under the sublime text menu item go to preferences and click on "Settings Syntax specific". You get a file that shows setting for spell checking. If that is true, try to change it to false.

Comment: Just checked and "spell_check" is set to "false".